# Нужен ли мне id в базе данных sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

У меня есть `SQLite` база данных в которую я добавляю избранные предметы, вопрос такой: нужен ли обязательно id? Из базы данных я планирую извлекать все просто в массив и далее работать с ним.

Answer (score 4):

Если планируешь изменять или удалять записи или если будут связи между таблицами, то нужен

```
id integer primary key autoincrement
```